# Can't open Natron on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

I have tried to install and use [Natron Softaware](https://natron.inria.fr/) for Ubuntu, but when it finished install, it didn't open and show a message `Missing OpenGL requirements`

Please, see the pic

[image: here]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you know what are the OpenGL requirements for this package: version, install configuration etc?

Comment: @Ketan No, I just know what is written here https://natron.inria.fr/plug-in-registry/

Comment: In which steps did you install it ?